# What is LenB actually doing on none string parameters

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have this bit of code that is being converted from vb6 to vb.net. I need to know what LenB is doing in this bit of code.

```
Dim singleValue As Single 'var for conversion use(4byte -> 1single)'
Dim bytes() As Byte
Dim valueB() As Byte 'this gets set elsewhere and is redim-d to its size'

For n = 0 To CDbl(ItemNumberCombo.Text) - 1
    'bytes() -> single'
    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: LenB function is not supported.'
    ReDim bytes(LenB(singleValue) - 1)
    bytes(3) = valueB(n * 4)
    bytes(2) = valueB(n * 4 + 1)
    bytes(1) = valueB(n * 4 + 2)
    bytes(0) = valueB(n * 4 + 3)
    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: LenB function is not supported.'
    'UPGRADE_ISSUE: VarPtr function is not supported. '
    Call memcpy(VarPtr(singleValue), VarPtr(bytes(0)), LenB(singleValue))
    'display the result'
    DText(n).Text = VB6.Format(singleValue, "0.000000E+00") 'CStr(singleValue)'
    If DataSaveCheckBox.CheckState = 1 And FileNameText.Text <> "" Then
        csvOutput = csvOutput & DText(n).Text & ","
    End If
Next n
```

Am I right in thinking that bytes is always ReDim'ed to the same size? By the looks of it 4 elements.

Why then use LenB to ReDim if you could just use a number? And why ReDim in the loop at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LenB() returns the length in bytes of a variable.  The most common example is for strings, where it returns the size of the string in bytes rather than the number of characters, regardless of character encoding.  For other types it returns the size of an object- the size of a single being 4.  The reason they would do this is that they wanted the code to survive if a future version of visual basic ever changed the size of a single (never mind hard-coding the number 4 when assigning to the byte array).

When upgrading LenB() to .Net, for strings use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` to get an array already populated with your string text bytes.  Remember that .Net always uses Unicode for strings internally.  If you really need a different encoding there are a number of alternatives in the Encoding namespace.  For other types use the `BitConverter` class.  Either way, don't go line by line as the newer methods take away a lot of the busy work.

Here — I'll help you out with the conversion some:

(earlier)

```
Dim csvOutput As New StringBuilder()
```

(later)

```
Dim valueB() As Byte 'this gets set elsewhere and is redim-d to its size'
Dim singleValue As Single 'var for conversion

' Included because the original developer was concerned the size of a single could change
Dim singleSize As Integer = BitConverter.GetBytes(singleValue).Length 

Dim NumberItems As Double
If Double.TryParse(ItemNumberCombo.Text, NumberItems) Then
    For n As Integer = 0 To NumberItems - 1
        singleValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(valueB, n * singleSize)

        'display the result
        DText(n).Text = singleValue.ToString("E6") 'CStr(singleValue)
        If DataSaveCheckBox.CheckState = 1 AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileNameText.Text) Then
            csvOutput.Append(DText(n).Text & ",")
        End If
    Next n
Else
    ' Handle Invalid ComboBox value here- may not be an issue for you
End If
```

Note that this code also demonstrates a `StringBuilder` as a *much* better way to build your csv data, the `AndAlso` operator, the `.TryParse()` methods, `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`, and Standard Format Strings, all of which are intended to replace constructs or techniques from vb6.

Comment: For scalar types, Len and LenB both return the size of the data. In this case, if you pass a Single to LenB, it will return 4 (a Single occupies 4 bytes of memory). It looks like the code is trying to reconstitute Singles from an array of bytes.

Comment: "length in bytes of a string, regardless of things like character encoding" - that does not compute. A string only has a length of actual *characters* if you don't regard encoding. Also, wasn't the question what LenB() does on *other* types?

Comment: @bzlm:  the individual characters that make up that string may not all  occupy the same number of bytes.  The string "dog" may be more than 3 bytes long for many encodings.

Comment: Updated wording to please the critics

Comment: +1 will check it out at work tomorrow and make sure it works before I accept it :) Not that I don't trust the correctness just want to make sure it fits with the rest of the code.

Comment: Don't forget to adjust for the stringbuilder

Answer (score 3):

Trying to explain bad code... is just an effort in futility.
Interesting way to fill a Single by loading a byte array.

The LenB function gives you the length in bytes of a variable.
Yes it will always return 4 when passed a Single variable type.

My guess for the redim is so the array gets initialized instead of preserved.
But since it then assigns all 4 bytes, it isn't technically needed and is probably just defensive programming.  Defensive programming might also explain the LenB.  In case Single changes size in the future.

Comment: I get the funny feeling a C programmer was forced to use VB6. ;-)

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, looks like they even aliased RtlMoveMemory to "memcpy". Oh, they were really missing C that day :-P

Comment: LOL! All VB programmers know Bruce McKinney christened it CopyMemory and no other name can ever be used, or it won't work